# Problem with persisting a list of objects into MYSQL database using spring boot

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, rest, jpa

I'm building a microservices architecture using spring boot. Now I run into a weird problem, which I don't know how to solve...

On of the services is a SongService, which provides endpoints for songs as well as for songLists.

My data model looks like this:

[image: data_model]

**The POST-Method in the SongListController works in this way:** A User can post a new SongList as Json by sending a POST-Request to http://localhost:8082/rest/v1/songlists/<userId(int)>. The SongService gets the User, sets the listOwner=userName and stores the SongList into the database using JpaRepositoriy.

My Entity Class looks like this:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Entity
public class SongList {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "songlist_id", updatable = false, nullable = false, unique = true)
    private int songListId;

    @Column(length = 45)
    private String OwnerId;

    @Column(length = 45, nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private boolean isPrivate;

    @ManyToMany()
    @JoinTable(name = "songlist_song",joinColumns ={ @JoinColumn( name = "songlist_id", 
        referencedColumnName = "song_id")}, inverseJoinColumns ={ @JoinColumn( name ="song_id", referencedColumnName = "song_id")})
    private List<Song> songs;
```

}

If I call the POST-Method, as described above, the SongsList gets persisted inside the songs_list table inside my MYSQL database, but without any songs - means, the songlist_song table stays empty. And if I GET the SongsList, I get it back without songs inside.

This is the corresponding code in my SongsListController:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/{userId}", consumes = "application/json")
public ResponseEntity<String> postNewSongList(@PathVariable(value = "userId") Integer userId,@RequestBody SongList songList) {

    if (songList.getName() == null || songList.getName().equals("") || songList.getName().trim().isEmpty())
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);

    int songListId = songListService.saveNewSongList(userId, songList);

    if (songListId == -1)
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);

    HttpHeaders header = new HttpHeaders();
    header.set("Location", "/rest/v1/songlists/" + songListId);
    return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(header).body("");
}
```

And this is the saveNewSongList-Method in my SongListService:

```
@Override
public int saveNewSongList(int userId, SongList songList) {
    User user = restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:8081/rest/v1/user/" + userId, User.class);
    if (user == null)
        return -1;

    if (songList.getSongs() != null) {
        for(Song song : songList.getSongs())
            if (songRepository.findById(song.getId()).isEmpty())
                return -1;
    }

    songList.setOwnerId(user.getUserId());
    SongList savedSongList = songListRepository.save(songList);
    return savedSongList.getSongListId();
}
```

THERE'S NO ERROR and that's why I don't know how to debug this...

I think, I did something wrong with this @JoinTable-Annotation, but cannot see what.

I'd be very glad, if someone could give me a hint on how to solve this...

Thank you very much!